# Force absolutely-positioned elements to inherit transparency

Tags: css, opacity

When an element is given an `opacity`, all static and relative children of the element are rendered with partial transparency. However, elements with `position: absolute` (or `position: fixed`) do not inherit this, and are instead rendered at full opacity unless specifically told otherwise.

Now, I could replace assignments to `style.opacity` with a call to a function that performs the assignment, then loops through all children, getting their computed style and seeing if their position property warrants the addition of its own `style.opacity`... but that's a bit of a nuke.

I also know that I could add `opacity: inherit` to the appropriate elements, but this only works if they are direct children of the faded element - what if they're descendants?

I'd like to know if there is a way to force elements to inherit the correct transparency.

Side-note: IE performs the way I want when I use `filter:alpha(...)`, interestingly enough.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate any of the behavior you describe. On IE, my absolutely-positioned element never receives transparency, even with `filter`. On all other browsers, the absolutely-positioned element behaves like all the other children, rendered with the same opacity as what is set on the parent element.

Comment: [Made a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/) - just tested in Chrome and you're right, this does seem to be an IE-specific issue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as it turned out, the answer was simply "make sure the absolute elements have a relative container that is affected by the transparency". I forgot to.

Comment: Nice find!  That's what I was looking for too.  I'm sure it's all explained here, if only a human being could read it: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#opacity

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, it does seem to be an IE only issue. It also seems to be a bug you need to work around. However setting on the positioned element only...

```
opacity: inherit; /* IE9 */
filter: inherit; /* IE8 */
```

...in IE8-9 [*does* propagate to children](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/4/) of the `absolute` element inheriting the `opacity`, *assuming those children themselves [do not have `position`](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/5/) set* ([even `position: relative` for IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/6/); however, [a later experiment in IE9](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/10/) showed that a grandchild of the `absolute` element seemed to stay hidden when itself was also `position: absolute`). Any other positioned children would need the same. IE7 (if you care) failed in evening having the `inherit` to work on the `filter`.

[IE9 could be resolved by having `position: relative` set](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/12/) to the `#container` without any `inherit` set on `#contained`, but that could seriously affect your positioning of `absolute` children (though not `fixed` ones).

**If you are dealing with many positioned elements within**, then I would recommend *conditionally feeding* [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/8/) to IE9 and under (I did not test IE10).

```
#container * {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);    
}
```

Comment: Of course it propagates to children - that's because IE8 supports `inherit`. It does not, however, propagate to grandchildren, etc unless they have inherit as well. If you make grandchildren inherit, but not children, then the children will pass their `opacity: 1` to the grandchildren, giving no apparent effect. However, the fiddle does not demonstrate using arbitrarily-nested descendants (grandchildren, etc). Also, IE7 does not support `inherit` on anything.

Comment: @BoltClock--the `p` tag in the first fiddle does not have `position` nor `opacity` set, yet it _does_ disappear, indicating that it accepted the `opacity` from the parent `contained` element in IE8-9 _until_ the `p` itself gained `position` (the second fiddle). Here's a bit more ["arbitrarily-nested" grand-children](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/9/), all hiding inside the original `absolute` container inheriting `opacity`, as [long as they have no `position` in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zqd6/10/) (I noticed in IE9, it worked on `absolute` grandchildren of the `absolute` element).